# Angular: Configure height of component inside<router-outlet> to fill parent of <router-outlet> element

Tags: css, angular, routes, sass, flexbox

What I am struggling to understand, is what is the right approach for components inside a  to reach the size of the element containing the . For example, this code:

**styles.sass**

```
body
    margin: 0 // ensures navbar sticks to top and sides
    display: flex // ensures footer stays at the bottom of the page
    flex-direction: column // ensures footer stays at the bottom of the page
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="view-height">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-button 
      [routerLink]="'home'">
      Home
      </button>
      <button mat-button (click)="setMenu('STATIC_DATA')"
      [routerLink]="'workbench'">
      Workbench
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <div class="router-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.sass**

```
.view-height
  min-height: 100vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column

.router-wrapper
  background-color: yellow
  flex: 1 1 auto
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
```

**app.workbench.html (target of [routerLink]="'workbench'")**

```
<div class="workbench-container">
</div>
```

app.workbench.sass

```
.workbench-container
    height: 10em
    background-color: blue
```

Leads to this:
[image: screenshot_current_layout]

**What I am trying to achieve:**
In simplified terms, I want the blue box to cover the entire yellow area.

**What I have tried:**

1. Flexbox flex-grow

Based on the router-wrapper  being a flexbox container, I tried setting flex: 1 1 auto or flex-grow: 1 respectively, on both .workbench-container and :host of the workbench.component.sass file, but neither had the desired effect.

2. Height 100%

It also had no effect and the .workbench-container remained at a height of 0.

I could not really find an answer based on the Angular tutorial at: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5#add-navigation-with-routing

The only way I found so far, is to set encapsulation to None, and adding the following snippet to
Turns out the solution could not be more simple:

The workbench.component.sass file allows to style the component with its selector, since it is simply a HTML element.

The solution here was therefore to simply add the following to the app-workbench.component.sass:

```
app-workbench
    flex: 1 1 auto
```

Is there any way at all without using encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution could not be more simple:

The workbench.component.sass file allows to style the component with its selector, since it is simply a HTML element.

The solution here was therefore to simply add the following to the app-workbench component:

```
app-workbench
    flex: 1 1 auto
```